# Working With 2 Independant projects c# and VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, design-patterns

I have 2 completely independent projects one in vb and one in c#

**Project A** - VB

**Project B** - C#

We have scenario where by code in project A is currently using code in project B 
e.g

**Project A**

```
Public Class SMS
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function SendSMS() As String
        Return "SMS Sent "
    End Function
End Class
```

**Project B**

```
using ProjectA;
    public class Email
    {      
        public string SendEmail()
        {
        return "Email Sent ";
        }

        public string SendEmail(SMS sms)
        {
            sms.SendSMS();
            return "Email Sent ";
        }
    }
```

This works fine However we now have a requirement to Send an Email from Project A which would create a circular reference After reading loads of help on here I created an interface and used the interface in project a as such:

**Project C**

```
Public Class Interface
    Public Interface IEmail
        Sub SendEmail()
    End Interface
End Class
```

I have implemented the interface on  Email and changed **Project A** to :

```
Public Function SendSMS(ByVal tEmail As IEmail) As String
    tEmail.SendEmail()
    Return "SMS Sent "
End Function
```

Which works fine from my ui as I can instantiate the object and all works fine.
However I have run into an issue where by I don’t want to instantiate the bject in the UI but instead in the **Project A**

```
Public Sub SendSMSAndEMail()
    Dim temail As New email
    Me.SendSMS(temail)
End Sub
```

I have hit a real road block? i think i should be looking at a factory class but i am getting confused as to how best to achieve this?

N.B Further info:

If we were to Design the system again project A and Project B would be in the same project (and Language) and this would not cause an issue. As it is we have 2 UI's A Console server app and a Win forms UI. Project B was originally for the console app and uses various functions that the main Win form app uses. It’s now arisen that there is code in the console app that we require from within the main app such as the ability to Send An E-mail however the code would be difficult to extract from the console app as it’s in a different language to the main application.

Comment: Why you want to instantiate the object in Project A in the first place?

Comment: We require an E-mail confimration of SMS messages that have been sent out. The Current Sending process of SMS messages is Handled within Project A. (not shown for simplicity? can you suggest another approach then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Evil solution: Static Factory Function**

Declare this static class in your root project (example in interface project).

```
public static class EmailFactory{
    public static Func<IEmail> Create{ get;set; }
}
```

Then in your UI (I assume that your Project will end up starting in UI), set it like:

```
EmailFactory.Create = new Func<IEmail>( () => { return new ProjectB.Email() } );
```

This way you can use it statically from Project A (even you still need to execute it from UI).

**But forget it, you won't need it. Or at least, don't use it.**

If you said that

> > The Current Sending process of SMS messages is Handled within Project A.

Does it means that Project A can be executed directly? I hope not. A library being executed is kind of evil for me. If you can, make the execution in separate project, and that project can reference to Project A and B as well. If so, then your `interface approach` is already fulfill the requirement.

EDIT:

Looks like the Project A or B itself is at UI level. It is a bad design to has library code inside UI project. However it will take months to refactor the whole application.

What I can suggest is to create a layer of library, which need to be used interactively between the project. So the architecture shall be:

```
     infrastructure
           |
           |
        library
        /     \
       /       \
[Project A]  [Project B]
```

IMHO this is the only way to fix your problem.

Comment: The UI Doesnt have knowledge of the SMS or EMail Being sent as they are called in the background and sent when certain events occur. As such i cannot intiate the objects at the UI level i am forced to do so within Project A or B.

Comment: Looks like Project A is being executed directly. I don't think that is a good approach. Do you has any problem to create another project (console app) to do the task instead directly from Project A?

Comment: If we were to Design the system again project A and Project B would be in the same project and this would not cause an issue. As it is we have 2 UI's A Console server app and a Win forms UI. Project B was originally for the console app and uses various functions that the main Win form app uses. It’s now arisen that there is code in the console app that we require from within the main app such as the ability to Send An E-mail however the code would be difficult to extract from the console app as it’s in a different language to the main application.

Comment: How about creating another layer of library project, and migrate some required logics to the library? Sorry, I cannot know what you can and what you can't.

Comment: It sounds like that may be possible do you have an example of how that would work?